# Why a RESTful web service can not call semaphore.acquire() properly?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, semaphore

I have a web service with the following methods code:

```
private static Semaphore reacted = new Semaphore(0);

@Path("/p1")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UserDefinedClass postMethod1( UserDefinedClass udc) {
   If (Condition A)
      semaphore.acquire();

   System.out.println("Test");

   UserDefinedClass u = new UserDefinedClass(udc);
   return u;
}

@Path("/p2")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void postMethod2(UserDefinedClass udc) throws IOException {
    ...
    reacted.release();
}
```

If Condition A does not occur, the service replies correctly to the calling environment (let's name it as CE), however, if Condition A is true, the method postMethod1 blocks waiting for somebody to invoke postMethod2.

If somebody calls postMethod2 (within 1 min from CE call to postMethod1). postMethod1 gets unblocked, however, the code below semaphore.acquire(); never gets executed and the "Test" message is not printed out rather I get the following error in CE:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=utf-8, type=class...
```

Please note that if Condition A was not true, no error is shown in CE. That means the issue is not with the method definition rather it is because the method's thread goes into the wait state waiting for the semaphore.

The CE code is:

```
    UserDefinedClass udc = new UserDefinedClass();

    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);

    String targetUrl = "http://localhost:8080/myApp";

    WebTarget target = client.target(targetUrl);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.path("rest").
            path("p1").
            request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(udc, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    UserDefinedClass u = response.readEntity(UserDefinedClass.class);
```

So what could be the issue?!

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint and see what is happening?

Comment: It was an issue caused by the server war causing it to return null if (Condition A) was true. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in your scripting language but the content type `text/html` is wrong.

I am also not sure if it's the response or request part but it does not match or properly set `APPLICATION_JSON`.

You should be easily able to solve this by investigating the real network traffic (I use `ngrep` for that, but others prefer `tcpdump`).

Comment: The language is JAVA. There is no issue in the response type as I have already said in my question that the postMethod1 works smoothly if Condition A was not true. So, if there was an issue in the response type, it should not work at all.

Comment: The major issue is that the postMethod1 thread is not pursuing the execution after the semaphore is acquired. I do not know why!

Comment: You're getting text/html on the response because there is an error on the server, and the server is actually responding with an error html page. It's always a good idea to check the status on the Response before calling readEntity. I bet it will be a 500, meaning a server error. You need to do some debugging on the server.